# Hidden, concealed, imperceptible; What word is missing?

Tags: word

**What word is missing?**

```
hidden          
concealed      
imperceptible  
inconspicuous  
indiscernible   
obscured     
unseen            
shrouded          
unnoticeable      
unseeable         
cloaked           
imperceivable
undetectable        
unnoticed          
unobserved        
clouded          
discreet     
disguised       
indistinct     
surreptitious  
unexposed      
unobtrusive     
camouflaged  
eclipsed         
inappreciable 
masked          
nonexistent      
obscure         
secret       
shadowy         
unapparent     
undercover     
undetected     
unperceivable   
unrevealed   
veiled          
covered          
covert          
ethereal         
gaseous         
ghostly      
imaginary     
impalpable    
imponderable  
insensible    
intangible       
latent       
perdu            
screened      
undisclosed     
unobservable  
vaporous
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The missing word is

> Invisible

If you

> Highlight the shape of the spaces after the words in the formatted block, you can see the edges of the letters INVISIBLE from top to bottom

Like this

> [image]